# How to run rpc in Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rpc

I want to execute a basic C program involving RPC. However, when I try to run it on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (using WSL) I get the following error:

```
mugdha@LAPTOP-1ME15EK1:~$ rpcinfo

rpcinfo: can't contact rpcbind: RPC: Remote system error - No such file or directory
```

[Error even though rpbind is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKk5Q.png)

Comment: Just for reference and better understanding, there are [many reasons why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) you shouldn't use images for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

Enable the `rpcbind` and `nfs` services:

```
sudo update-rc.d rpcbind enable
sudo update-rc.d nfs-common enable
```

Then restart the rpcbind service:

```
sudo service rpcbind restart
```

Comment: Note that `update-rc.d` has no effect on WSL, since it doesn't run services at startup using SysVInit.  The answer was (and this is a bit of an old question), likely just `sudo service rpcbind start`.  Just a heads-up that the person who asked this hasn't been on the site in over a month, and likely they either solved it a long time ago or moved on. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try to see path where pkg accurately install.

```
which rpcinfo
```

maybe this problem related to port, When you start a server in WSL, both windows and linux share the same localhost. for more see port forwarding [port forwarding](https://dev.to/vishnumohanrk/wsl-port-forwarding-2e22) .